Newbie Power Pivot Help - RANKX Function
I'm trying to rank a value within a pivot table to be able to then reference it in a calculated field. I've been unable to use the 'Value Field Settings', 'Show Value As' steps to reference the rank and after some help from ChatGPT, it seems I need to create a measure to rank the value via Power Pivot.
I've added my table to the Data Model and want to try and rank a value of each horse in a race at a particular time, I've included a screenshot of the ranked value created in the 'Value Field Settings' to show you what I mean.
My table contains fields for the date, time, horse and value that I'm trying to rank but when trying to create the RANKX measure, I always seem to be either getting an error or returning incorrect information.
I'm after some help on the correct RANKX formula to be able to return the information I need?
Thanks,
Martin.Screenshot example

It would help if you supplied some sample data in copiable format and expected results.

Thanks for responding @davidebacci
I've managed to figure out how to do this with the following formula.
=RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(ProformExports4,ProformExports4[Race Date],ProformExports4[Race Time_1]),CALCULATE(SUM([321_Value])))
What I'm finding is though if I'm using the same to rank numbers containing a negative number,  I'm getting some odd results. The positive numbers rank fine  but the negative numbers don't.
The rank will run 1, 2 , 3 then a negative number will jump to 4436, 4437 etc.
Is there something different I need to do that accommodates negative numbers?
